# Landing in systemd emergency prompt after lengthy boot repair process. Problem: Missing FS in fstab flile

Tags: boot, systemd, fstab, grub-efi, multi-user

I realize there's been several questions by people who've had issues booting already, but I think mine is a rather particular case, so I'm posting yet another question in hopes of addressing some new issues.

I've been repairing the boot process of a VM that had an `initramfs` (`initrd.img` and `vmlinuz` files in `/boot`) from kernels that were no longer installed, and was trying to still boot from them.

I am very close to being finished, but it keeps rebooting into `systemd`'s `emergency mode` (where it says: )

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Give root password for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

I booted from a live CD, mounted the 3 pertinent partitions to `/mnt`, chrooted to `/mnt`:

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in proc dev dev/pts sys tmp run; do mount --bind /$i /mnt/$i; done
chroot /mnt
```

Did my repairs and rebooted.

Now my `fstab` is not mounting my partitions.  I thought it was correctly configured - UUIDs are copied directly from `blkid | grep /dev/sda`.  I didn't think it was missing anything.

Here are the errors I'm seeing right before getting to the emergency mode prompt:

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount /boot
See 'systemctl status boot.mount' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Unattended Upgrades Shutdown
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi
```

So, of course I looked at `systemctl status boot.mount`, but it's active (green) and says it's loaded, even though my `/boot` folder is empty unless I manually mount `/dev/sda2`.

Seems very strange. Why would `boot.mount` say it's loading `/boot` partition if it's clearly not?

Comment: I enjoyed reading this, but to fit the format of this site it needs to be a q&a. Most of this reads more like an answer. It's fine to answer your own question; consider an edit to make this a q&a.

Comment: Hello. You might have more luck if you could be more specific about what exact problem you need an answer to. There is a lot of text, and it's hard for me to see which parts are relevant for your specific problem.

Comment: Hi, yeah that was kind of the point. Not at first, but then I fixed the problem while I was asking the question. I will try and succinct it up a bit.

Comment: Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 2):

So I actually figured out the issue while I was writing the question.  As you can see from what I wrote in the beginning, it was a very long process (I had been working on it for about 2 days before I got to the point of wanting to ask for help).

If you look at the very end of the Q, I had received this message from `dmesg` during the boot process:

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount /boot
See 'systemctl status boot.mount' for details.
```

So, of course I tried `systemctl status boot.mount` to see what it said, but it said `boot.mount` is active (green), it's loaded and functioning properly, even though `/boot` was empty unless I manually mounted `/dev/sda2` (which is exactly the opposite of what I would expect).

So I started thinking something might be wrong with the service.  I disabled `boot.mount` even though it *said* it was working properly:

```
systemctl disable --now boot.mount
```

I tried to re-enable it, but got an error:

```
systemctl enable --now boot.mount
Failed to enable unit: Unit /run/systemd/generator/boot.mount is transient or generated
```

OK, that makes sense, it's triggered through the boot process and cannot be invoked through a user command.  So I tried to re-mount all devices with:

```
mount -a
```

And saw that there was an error in the `/etc/fstab` file:

```
error: rw,relatime is not a valid file system
```

(or something to that effect).

The key here is, if I hadn't tried mounting the filesystem manually, I would have never received that feedback.  The error message from `mount -a` one gets when `fstab` contains improper syntax is incredibly helpful.  A lot more helpful than:

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount /boot
See 'systemctl status boot.mount' for details.
```

... and then seeing a "working" systemd unit for `boot.mount` when `/boot` is not mounting (even though it *did* get me to the right place eventually).

So I edited the `fstab` and entered the filesystem info for the `/boot` partition that failed to mount, then I re-ran `mount -a` (which essentially does the same thing as `boot.mount`) and got a positive response.

Now the two partitions are mounting properly after a reboot, and all is good in the land of horseradish and marmalade.

If this does not address any of your issues, here are some additional notes of the process I went through before getting to the point above where I was looking for help (feel free to stop reading after you get to your problem):

The original issue I was having two days ago was the system trying to boot from kernels no longer on the system.  So, after booting with the live CD, I deleted the `/boot` folder's contents (where all the `initrd` files are located).

I figured I would just re-create the `initramfs` using `update-initramfs -c -k all` from the current kernels I had installed, but then I learned that I could not re-create the `config` or `System.map` files with `depmod` alone. This turned out to be a little more troublesome than I had bargained for.

I found the easiest way to re-generate or acquire all these files is to:

1. delete all contents of `/boot`,
2. uninstall any `linux-image`, `linux-header` and `linux-modules` files I had no intention of using,
3. delete all residual directories in `/usr/lib/modules`, and then
4. re-install `linux-image`, `linux-modules` and `linux-headers` files I intended on using (the most current generic two versions)

Note: Re-installing these 3 types of files *all at the same time* was how I managed to get the `/boot/System.map` and `/boot/config` files back - before only re-installing the `linux-image` files did not do it.  It's possible they're included with `modules` (modules would make sense), or `headers` packages, but this is what worked for me.

5. Then I ran `update-grub` after re-installing those files and confirming `/boot` was populated correctly.
6. I also ran `bootctl install` and `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-udpate-systemd-boot`, so I would have `systemd-boot` installed as a fallback.

At one point after a reboot, I had to re-configure `system.target` to `multi-user.target` instead of `graphical.target`, probably due to having `chroot`ed with all those mounts in a graphical live CD to run the `boot-repair` program a couple days ago, which requires graphics (and I believe `/dev/pts` `/tmp` and `/run` were required to get `display :0.0` to work):

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Ok that's about it. Hope this helps someone.